# $f_n \to f$ pointwise implies $f_n$ is bounded

Tags: sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

If $f_n$ and $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, E is a bounded set, and $f_n \to f$ pointwise on E, is it true that each function $f_n$ is bounded on E?

Comment: No...take $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{n}$ on $(0,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f_n(x)=\frac 1 {nx}$ on $E=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$.